# Breezejs inline count

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, odata, breeze

In BreezeController:

```
public IQueryable<Entities> Index()
{
    return this.context.entities.Where(e => e.value > 100);
}
```

Breeze query  `query.inlineCount(true)` returns count after Where, but how I can return count of entities before Where statement or manually set count to response? I know about filters, but in my task I need Where statement right in action.

Comment: Can you show the action method.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot name for action method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me

```
[Breeze.WebApi.BreezeController]
public class MyBreezeController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
    private readonly Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider<MyDbContext> context
        = new Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider<MyDbContext>();

    [SetInlineCountFilter]
    [Breeze.WebApi.BreezeQueryable]
    public System.Linq.IQueryable<MyEntity> Index()
    {
        return this.context.Context.MyEntities.Where(e => e.Value > 100);
    }
}

public class SetInlineCountFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var content = (System.Net.Http.ObjectContent)actionExecutedContext.Response.Content;
        var result = (Breeze.WebApi.QueryResult)content.Value;
        result.InlineCount = 42;
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Now you can get value of inlinecount from anywhere and add code for pass it to filter

Or doing all sevrer-side breeze work manually:

```
[Breeze.WebApi.BreezeController]
public class MyBreezeController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
    private readonly Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider<MyDbContext> context
        = new Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider<MyDbContext>();

    public QueryResult Index()
    {
        return new QueryResult
                   {
                       InlineCount = 42,
                       Results = this.context.Context.MyEntities.Where(e => e.Value > 100)
                   };
    }
}
```

And get query options from request `this.Request.RequestUri.Query`